# Struggling to pass a parameter as an event in an Angular 1.6 component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been tasked with developing an app in Angular 1.6, and I have not done any Angular 1.x for quite some time. Been mostly doing 2.x. In fact, never done 1.6 at all.

I have two components: a tile container, and a tile. The tiles are selectable, so I imagined having a tile container component that would keep track of which tile was selected, and a tile component which is primarily a UI component.

My tile component looks like this:

```
// dp-claim-filter-tile.component.js
function ClaimFilterTileController() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.isDisabled = () => {
        return ctrl.claimCount == 0;
    }

    ctrl.test = function () {
        console.log('ctrl = ' + JSON.stringify(ctrl));
        ctrl.onTileClicked(ctrl);
    }
}

angular.module('dpApp').component('dpClaimFilterTile', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/dp-claim-filter-tile.tmpl.html',
    controller: ClaimFilterTileController,
    bindings: {
        tileTitle: '@',
        claimCount: '@',
        isAdd: '<',
        isActive: '<',
        onTileClicked: '&'
    }
});
```

And the template looks like this:

```
// dp-claim-filter-tile.tmpl.html
<div ng-if="$ctrl.isAdd===true" layout="column" layout-align="space-around center">
    <div><h2 class="md-title">{{$ctrl.tileTitle}}</h2></div>
    <div>
        <md-icon md-font-icon="fa-plus" class="fa fa-2x"></md-icon>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="$ctrl.isAdd!==true" layout="column" layout-align="space-around center" ng-click="$ctrl.test()">
    <div><h2 class="md-title tile-text">{{$ctrl.tileTitle}}</h2></div>
    <div class="md-display-1 tile-text">{{$ctrl.claimCount}}</div>
</div>
```

The tile container component looks like this:

```
// dp-claim-filter-tiles.component.js
function ClaimFilterTilesController() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.tileClicked = function(tile) {
        console.log('tile = ' + JSON.stringify(tile));
    }
}

angular.module('dpApp').component('dpClaimFilterTiles', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/dp-claim-filter-tiles.tmpl.html',
    controller: ClaimFilterTilesController
});
```

And an extract of the container UI looks like this:

```
// dp-claim-filter-tiles.tmpl.html
<md-grid-tile>
    <dp-claim-filter-tile is-active="true" tile-title="Links Sent" claim-count="7" on-tile-clicked="$ctrl.tileClicked($event)"></dp-claim-filter-tile>
</md-grid-tile>
```

What I am expecting, and hoping for, is for the `$event` parameter I am supplying to surface as a parameter to the `ClaimFilterTilesController.tileClicked()` function.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The [click $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) will be available in the ngClick directive by itself, you won't be able to carry it around before the actual ngClick directive gets triggered.

Therefore, you could access the click event exclusively in `dp-claim-filter-tile.tmpl.html` template, like this:

```
ng-click="$ctrl.test($event, otherParam)"
```

Comment: But I don't want to access the click event, I am interested in passing a reference to the tile that has been clicked back up to the tile container.

Comment: Use service to hold the event variable, or even a notifier structure to communicate properly between the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `ng-click` rather than the `on-tile-clicked`. This way you can get at the `$event` object which can be passed into other functions within your component definition.

```
<md-grid-tile>
    <dp-claim-filter-tile-is-active="true" tile-title="Links Sent" claim-count="7" ng-click="$ctrl.tileClicked($event)"></dp-claim-filter-tile>
</md-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Same answer as above:I don't want to access the click event, I am interested in passing a reference to the tile that has been clicked back up to the tile container.

Comment: Okay, I can update the answer with a different solution. Would you be willing to use $scope or `$rootScope` `$emit`? I know your not currently injecting `$scope`, but send/receive/listen to events that way. You won't get the $event object. Do you need the $event object even?

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I don't really want to be introducing `$scope` to be honest. May get into bother with that. What is `$emit`? I shall look that up! It's not the click event from the tile that is causing the problem, it's raising the event _and passing a parameter_ on my '&' event parameter...

Comment: I don't blame you for not wanting `$scope`. `$emit` and `$broadcast` let you effectively create/send custom events out that can be listened to in other components utilizing `$scope` or `$rootScope`. It can be pretty handy working with "global" events, but makes you depend on `$scope` unfortunately. What reference you do specifically need? The rendered DOM element or a specific property of one of these tile component items?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a service as a Notifier

Comment: I need a reference to the component instance, along with all of its properties. Maybe I've inculcated 2.x thinking and need to readjust for 1.6!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the [AngularJS site](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component): Intercomponent Communication. The trick lies in using the `require` property when defining the component. You can essentially create a reference to the enclosing component. Shall implement tomorrow.

Thanks for your answers guys.